# Using Html or javascript, how to set the height and width of a button to the ones of the parent div

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html. And I know that the parent div with the `id="id1"` has been set its height and width in the css file. For this context, how can you set the height and width of the button to the same height and width of the parent div? In detail, I don't want to check the values in the css file for some reason.

```
<div id="id1">    
<button type="button" >Hello<button/>    
</div>
```

As a post script:
Let me explain some additional context. I cannot change the css because it is not mine. So I can't change that the parent div is defined its height and width by its id.
Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want a pure HTML and JavaScript solution without adding or modifying any CSS?

Comment: @user3259983, Yes, I do. The CSS file will not be written by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use: 
`width: 100%; height: 100%;` 
or `width: inherit; height: inherit;` on child.

view solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/zryd01r6/

Comment: can you share your code, or create a fiddle with a part of your problem? try forcing: `margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;` on parent and child.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried it and partially got a good result. In detail, the resultant width is too short. But I think it is due to the complexty of the css files of the web site. I noticed that the parent div is not defined the height whereas it is defined its min-height.

Comment: Sorry. I should have wrote as "the resultant height is too short".

Comment: are you using any images? Also observe the precedence: IDs over Classes, Classes over Tags, Top to Bottom file execution (in case 2 classes change the same property, farthest down the file will take effect). If you send me your problem I can explain better what's wrong in your case.

Comment: finally I got the result. As I wrote in the last comment, I had given wrong information to every one here. Namely the parent div defined only its width and min-height. So I re tried your answer with min-height in place of height. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of use class instead of "id" because id is unique.

```
<button class="your-class-name" type="button" >Hello</button>
```

**[CSS]**

```
if your button is in a div:
.your-class-name{width:100%;height:100%}
Else mention its width and height as your expectation
.your-class-name{width:80px;height:40px}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it with some change and got a good result. But the change is due to that I incorrectly described the context. I edited your answer into: .your-class-name{width:inherit; min-height:inherit}

Answer (score 0):

After reading this several time I get what your issue is here. There are better ways of doing this in a team environment. Much better ways. BUT to answer your question exactly as you have stated.

```
<div id="id1">    
<button type="button" style="height:100%;width:100%">Hello</button>    
</div>
```

^ Breaks Proper Team Design Principles and SOC but answers your quesiton.

**This is not the best way to do things**

- You can load a separate file after the provided CSS file
- You can compile Sass in the correct order that would allow you to
  make such changes, say, devsass.sass commented well so the UX people
  can see what and why you are doing this and if they can deal with it themselves.
- Communicate

There seems to be no communications.

*To drive the point home it seems like you are asking for a way to screw with /  play a joke on the UX guys. This is just not the way to do this properly.*

Comment: many points in your answer which I should learn in my project.

Comment: @yuzu, your above comment is the exact developer attitude that is needed to master things, you make me wish I spent some more time on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="id1">    
<button class="id1" type="button" >Hello</button>
</div>
```

Try that, it makes the button have the same id of the div, so it should scale it to the same size as the main div.

EDIT:
Forgot you should use classes for multiple objects.

Comment: You should not reuse a id, consider a class instead

Comment: **ID**s are **unique** (use each ID only once). You meant to say **classes**.